# SQL Server : setting flag in original table to processed after copying data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table where I want to take the data from that table, and insert it into other (smaller) tables. But when doing this, I want to mark a column in the large table ("Processed") to true, so that the next time the query is run, it will not end up creating duplicates. Is there an easier way of doing this, other than creating the small query after-the-fact to set everything that is 0 to 1?  Or is this the most efficient way?

```
DECLARE @largeTable TABLE(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    productName varchar(100),
    productId int,
    quantity int,
    someVar int,
    Processed bit)

INSERT INTO @largeTable (productName, productId, quantity, someVar, Processed)
VALUES ('Apple', 1, 50, 34, 0),
        ('Orange', 2, 50, 53, 0),
        ('Banana', 3, 50, 165, 0),
        ('Pineapple', 4, 74, 34, 0),
    ('Mango', 5, 50, 388, 0),
        ('Kiwi', 6, 50, 2, 0),
        ('Strawberry', 7, 50, 16, 0)

SELECT * FROM @largeTable

DECLARE @smallTable TABLE(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    productName varchar(100),
    productId int)

INSERT INTO @smallTable (productName, productId)
SELECT productName, productId
FROM @largeTable
WHERE Processed = 0

UPDATE @largeTable
Set Processed = 1
WHERE Processed = 0

SELECT * FROM @largeTable
SELECT * FROM @smallTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of merge statement, here based on product id, you can find that if any row already exists, if yes then update it or else insert:

```
MERGE smalltable AS target
USING (SELECT productName, productId from largetable) AS source (productName, productId)
ON (target.productId = source.productId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET productName = source.productName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (productId, productName)
    VALUES (source.productId, source.productName)
```

Also, to get the ProductsId which are inserted so that you can update the Processed column, you can do the following:

```
  Update largetable
  set Processed=1
  from largetable join Inserted on largetable.Productid=Inserted.ProductId
```

Here, Inserted is a logical table created by SQL after Insert/update operation

Comment: Thank you, this helped tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to get the records that are not processed (Delta) and insert their Primary Keys values in a table variable, then use this info to manage transferring data from large table to small table and to update large table transferred records (update the flag).

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

DECLARE @ProccessTable TABLE (IsProcessed SMALLINT)

DECLARE @LargeTable TABLE ( 
                   field1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
                   field2 NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
                   field3 NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
                   field4 NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
                   IsProcessed SMALLINT NOT NULL  
                   )

INSERT INTO @LargeTable 
VALUES ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI',0), ('JKL','MNO','PQR',0), ('STU','VXY','ZAB',0)

SELECT * FROM @LargeTable WHERE IsProcessed = 0

DECLARE @SmallTable TABLE ( 
                   field1 INT NOT NULL, 
                   field2 NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
                   field3 NVARCHAR(50) NULL
                   )

INSERT INTO @ProccessTable
SELECT field1 FROM  @LargeTable WHERE IsProcessed = 0 

INSERT INTO @SmallTable
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM @LargeTable WHERE field1 IN (SELECT 
field1 FROM @ProccessTable)

UPDATE @LargeTable SET IsProcessed = 1 WHERE field1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM @ProccessTable)

SELECT * FROM @LargeTable WHERE IsProcessed = 0
SELECT * FROM @SmallTable

COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
ROLLBACK 
END CATCH
```